# ANTRL pretty error message in case of unbalanced brackits

Tags: error-handling, antlr, backtracking

My problem is if there is an unclosed parenthesis at the end of a document I got the error message: unexpected EOF. This is a bad message and I tried to avoid it.

My grammar has a global backtracking turned on.
Therefore an action is not called until entire rule is matched
and exceptions also are not thrown.

So I cannot use flag in the parser state or an exception handler to rethrow my own to terminate the parser.

Comment: You will not be able to have reasonable error handling ability until you disable backtracking.

Comment: I could if there is some unconditional action (let say {! if (...) throw new Exception() ; !} that executed any way nonetheless the backtracking flag because I know where check and how to do it.

Comment: In ANTLR 3, `{{ ... }}` is an embedded action that executes even during backtracking.